# Bad Request for using Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

While using Google Drive API's Get method to get document information of Google Docs (https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) , **I always get 400 Bad Request** with no clear explanation.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgzKH.png)

The explanation given in the JSON response is: "This operation is not supported for this document."

I get the same error executing the API in a simple node.js program.

By analysing the problem it only happens to when the API is called upon **google docs that were upload manually to Google drive.**

For documents created directly in Google Drive, this does not happen.

Manually uploaded documents always have .doc or .docx extension in the filename in Google drive (as per the image below).

[Document Manually Uploaded to Google Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bldfB.png)

Documents created directly in Google drive don't have the .doc or docx extension (don't know if related).

Anyone has idea why does it happen? Is there a workaround or a specific extra query parameter necessary?

Comment: Are you trying to directly access to Microsoft Word with Google Docs API? If it's so, such error occurs. In this case, it is required to convert from MIcrosoft Word to Google Document. By this, it can be accessed with Google Docs API. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Yes correct, it is a word document (.doc, docx) and not native Google Docs document. It seemed logic that the get() method of the API would be agnostic to that and that it would be able to fetch the document content regardless of the above (as you can manually convert between Word and Google Docs manually). Does Google offer an API to convert between types automatically?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. Google APIs have the methods for converting from Microsoft Docs to Google Docs. For example, as one of them, you can convert it using the method of Files: copy in Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy) You can test the method of Files: copy in Drive API by setting the file ID of Microsoft Word to `fileId` and setting mimeType to `application/vnd.google-apps.document`.

Comment: Awesome. It works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be also useful for other users who have the same issue.